# Is there a way to strip the high bit of each byte in a file?

Tags: sed, conversion, tr, byte

I've been trying to figure out if this can be done in `sed` or `tr`, but I can't find it.

I have a bunch of files from an old Apple II which have the high bit set on each byte. On a Mac, this results in a bunch of gibberish. Of course, I could write a program to xor $80 each byte, but I'm thinking that there MUST be a way in UNIX to do this!

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont think `sed` or `tr` or other text-oriented tool let you touch the byte in a file. You should open a file in byte-way ('rb') to do your changes. Maybe a little `py` or `perl` script can help

Comment: I'd rather AND each byte with x7f. Creating a longer sequence of x7f's and ANDing larger chunks of the file with it might be faster.

Comment: `tr '\200-\377' '\000-\177'` but if your `tr` supports multibyte (AFAIK GNU still doesn't) and your environment enables it, disable that first (PS: yay Apple II -- a friend of mine had one in 1976 IIRC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bbe`](http://bbe-.sourceforge.net) is "a sed-like editor for binary files". In Debian it's in the `bbe` package; I don't know if it's as easily available on Mac.

This performs binary AND with `0x7f` for each byte of input:

```
bbe -e '& \x7f'
```

Example usage:

```
<input_file bbe -e '& \x7f' >output_file
```

Comment: brew install bbe   :-)

Comment: To do it best for the Apple II:   <input_file bbe -e '& \x7f' | tr '\r' '\n' >output_file

Comment: @bjb No need to spawn `tr`. This: `bbe -e '& \x7f' -e 's/\r/\n/'`

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -wpe '$_ &= "\x7f" x length' < file
```

If you want to process the file line by line (e.g. when the file is too large to fit into memory), specify the hex line separator:

```
perl -0x8d ...
```

(I'm not sure whether 0x0d was newline on Apple II, so fix the value as you need).

Comment: Is 'length' a keyword in this case, or should I be replacing that with something? Out of the box it produces nothing (yes, I did replace 'file' with the source file name)

Comment: [length](http://p3rl.org/length) is indeed a keyword. Can you share a sample hexdump of the input?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/callapple/GBBS/master/Source/Acos/ACOS.S

Comment: @bjb: That's not a hexdump.